# Remove unused/empty screens on Square Home launcher

Tags: applications, launcher

I'm using the [Square Home](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.squarehome2) launcher and somehow, it creates additional home screens parallel to my main screen. I don't know what triggers this, but right now I have 23 home screens, and 22 of them are empty. And my contacts are at the farther right end of them. That is, I have to swipe left 24 times to reach my contacts from my home screen.

Normally, using the standard Android launcher, I could get rid of empty parallel home screens by pressing and holding some empty place and swiping up the empty home screens. However, that totally does not work here.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pinch out on the homescreen
- Tap the Edit icon on the bottom right corner.
- Delete button should appear

Check the screenshots below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Solved. I didn't think about pinching...